# How to use bearer authorization for robot framework requestlibrary

Tags: robotframework, web-api-testing

I m trying to use bearer authorization using requestlibary of robot framework.
Note:
${tokenval} getting value from another keyword.
${Body} value declared as a variable.

```
*** Test Cases ***
    Createnew
    ${tokenval}=     Get Token Client Credentials
    ${token1}=       Catenate  bearer  ${SPACE}  ${tokenval}
    ${headers}       content-type=application/json   Authorization=${token1}
    Create Session   apitest    https://testxxapi.com    ${headers}
    ${response}=     POST On Session   apitest   /deals/new   ${Body}
    ${resDict}=      convert to dictionary   ${response.json()}
    log              ${resDict}
```

But I m getting HTTPError: 403 Client Error.
Same request with bearer authorization working in postman.

Answer (score 1):

There's one issue with your code, and one potential you'd better change for the piece of mind.

The [Catenate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate) keyword combines its arguments in a single string using *(by default)* "space" as delimiter.
Thus after this call:

```
${token1}=       Catenate  bearer  ${SPACE}  ${tokenval}
```

, the value you get is `bearer   the_token` - 3 spaces b/n the two words. Drop the second argument, or just use

```
${token1}=       Set Variable    Bearer ${tokenval}
```

---

The other, potential issue is the casing of "Bearer" - [according to the specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) it should be treated case insensitive, but some Oauth 2.0 providers had bugs years ago where they expected it to be with a capital letter.

Comment: thank you for your reply. it really helped to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     API Testing in Robot Framework
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           Collections
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${dev_b_token}    Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI3R
${dev_b_server}    https://test-api-dev-b.apps.robot-b.osd.corp
${params}         kod=BI1K

*** Test Cases ***
Do a GET Request with Bearer token
&{headers}    Create Dictionary    Authorization=${dev_b_token}
Create Session    dev_b_session    ${dev_b_server}
Log    ${headers}
${response}=    GET On session    dev_b_session    /api/v1/test/info    headers=${headers}    params=${params}
Log    ${response}
Status Should Be    200    ${response}    #Check Status as 200
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).